# To what extent are cached instances used for common Float and Double values?

Tags: java, autoboxing

For Integer and some other numeric types, instances representing values in the range -128 to 127 are re-used when calling valueOf or autoboxing a primitive value.

But what about Float and Double? The [javadoc for valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf-float-) hints that it may likewise use cached values:

> If a new Float instance is not required, this method should generally
>   be used in preference to the constructor Float(float), as this method
>   is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values.

However, this statement is less definitive when compared to [Integer's valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) ("This method will always cache values in the range..."), and does not state a set of values for which this optimization might be in place. So how does this actually behave in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the implementation of `Float.valueOf` (JDK 8), I see that it just creates a new Float object by calling the constructor.

```
public static Float valueOf(float f) {
    return new Float(f);
}
```

So, it maybe an optimization for the future.

Answer (score 2):

While the Javadoc says caching may be used, I just checked the implementation in my JDK (version 8), and no caching is implemented:

```
public static Float valueOf(float f) {
    return new Float(f);
}

public static Double valueOf(double d) {
    return new Double(d);
}
```

I don't know how effective such caching can be. Unlike `Integer`, `Long`, `Byte`, `Short` and `Character` (where the cached values are a small sequence of consecutive numbers), it's less clear which `Double` and `Float` values should be cached.

Answer (score 0):

There is such caching mechanism for the Float wrapper similar to the one for Integer and it is in Java since the early days of the language.

The caching is done by an Array[] managed directly by the JVM. (that is why you will not find such an Float[] in the code for the wrapper class, it is simply not there.)

The size of this array can vary from JVM to JVM, however it guarantees that the size of it is at least 256.

It is generally as the docs say to use the valueOf(float f) method since it really does cache often used values. It just does it on a JVM level. The documentation says it for a reason and is not there just because.

Hope this helps and answers the question better! :)